# Hyperlink in apexpage.message

Tags: error-messages

How to add hyperlink in apexpage.message() in apex class? I got some [solution link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000094uhIAA) but it is displaying the message on the top of the visual force page. I want message in some division/section of page. Does anybody know anything about this. Please point me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it in a very simple way just using an `apex:pageMessage` tag and place it anywhere on the page:

```
<apex:pageMessage severity="warning" escape="false" summary="Summary text" strength="2" title="Message title text">
    <a href="#">The link test</a>
</apex:pageMessage>
```

The result:

[image]

If you have to conditionally render the message on the page you will have to define an apex boolean variable ant  put it into the `rendered="{!yourVariable}"` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you can put `<apex:pageMessages escape="false"/>` in apex pageblock, outputpanel etc. then if will be visible in there as well. You will need to `rerender` that section e.g. PageBlock.

```
    <apex:pageBlock title="Attendances" mode="edit" id="rerender_id">
       <apex:pageBlockSection title="Details" columns="2">
                  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                         <apex:pageMessages escape="false"/>
                  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
```